# virustotal.com API example in PHP?

Tags: php, json

Does anybody have a PHP example of using the VirusTotal.com public API for URL scanning?

The API is available here:
http://www.virustotal.com/advanced.html

There's a Python/JSON example, but I'm not experienced with either :(

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to retreive the report json using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) this way :

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.virustotal.com/api/get_url_report.json');
```

Then use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert your json into a php array:

```
$array = json_decode($json);
```

to see results :

```
var_dump($array);
```

to post data use curl, [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091623/sending-post-data-with-curl-and-php).

Comment: You can't make POST requests like this. Without the needed parameters, the site just returns `None`.

Comment: @svens, are you talking about posting data via CURL ?

Comment: More is needed than that. Please see the sections "Retrieve a URL scan report" and "Submit and scan a URL" under Public API on http://www.virustotal.com/advanced.html.

Comment: All is about sending parameters using POST, a good tutorial : http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html

Answer (score 0):

A PHP example is available on that page (maybe it's new).

Comment: You should give some example code for this by yourself. This way your answer may be valid if the page changes.